# Changing the shipping cost in paypal through code

Tags: paypal

Hi and thanks in advance for any help I can get.

I have a website selling safety products and ship to Australia and the USA.  Problem is that I have 2 different shipping charges depending on if it's Australia or USA and I don't know how to automate the different charge based on destination.  I use code something like the code pasted below.  Can I set something in that code that asks for shipping country? If not, how else can I solve this problem without manually configuring a shipping list for every single product in paypal?

Thanks thanks and more thanks. :)

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@yoursite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Baseball Hat">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="0.50">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="2.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shipping calculator](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/shipping/EasyCalculateShipAndTax-outside) to setup shipping based on country.

PayPal does not offer any code to calculate the shipping for PayPal Payments Standard buttons rather set shipping inside PayPal Profile. If you are using API, then you can use API parameters to setup shipping or use [Instant Update API.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/)